# ggsurvplot expand limits not aligning plot and table?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, survival

I am generating a kaplan-meir with a number at risk table using ggsurvplot. I want my axes expanded which is shown in the graph. However, this then means that the table does not line up with the plot. I want the axes expanded in the table as well so that they are aligned. How does one do this?

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(ggpp)

df <- lung

# surv time in months
df$time_months <- df$time/(365.25/12)

km_fit<- survfit(Surv(time_months, status) ~ sex, data = df)

time_int <- 2

# SURV FIT 

km_plot <- ggsurvplot(km_fit, 
                      data = df, 
                      risk.table = TRUE, 
                      fontsize = 3,
                      cumevents = FALSE,
                      # add.all = TRUE,
                      # cumevents.title = "Cumulative No. of Events",
                      risk.table.height = 0.18,
                      cumevents.height = 0.18,
                      break.x.by = time_int, # Set x-axis breaks to X months intervals (90 days)
                      x.tick.by = time_int, # Set x-axis tick marks to X months intervals (90 days)
                      time.inc = time_int, # Set risk table to group by X months intervals (90 days)
                      risk.table.by = time_int, # Set risk table to group by X months intervals (90 days)
                      legend.title = "", # Set legend title
                      tables.y.text = FALSE, # Remove text next to risk table and just have colours
                      surv.median.line = "hv",
                      xlim = c(0, max(km_fit$time*1.2)),
                      xlab = "Time (months)")

# Customise KM aesthetics 

km_plot$table <- km_plot$table +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, color = "black", face = "bold"))
km_plot$cumevents <- km_plot$cumevents +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, color = "black", face = "bold"))

km_plot$table$theme$axis.text.y$size <- 8
km_plot$cumevents$theme$axis.text.y$size <- 8
km_plot$table$theme$axis.text.x$size <- 8
km_plot$cumevents$theme$axis.text.x$size <- 8
km_plot$table$theme$axis.title.x$size <- 8
km_plot$cumevents$theme$axis.title.x$size <- 8

km_plot$plot <- km_plot$plot +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = seq(0,1,by=0.1), labels = seq(0,100,by=10), minor_breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = seq(0, round(max(km_plot$data.survplot$time*1.2)), time_int), minor_breaks = seq(0, round(max(km_plot$data.survplot$time*1.2)), time_int / time_int)) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(color = "grey80",
                                          linewidth = 0.5,
                                          linetype = 1),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(color = "grey80",
                                          linewidth = 0.5,
                                          linetype = 1),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "grey80",
                                          linewidth = 0.5,
                                          linetype = 1),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "grey80",
                                          linewidth = 0.5,
                                          linetype = 1)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12, color = "black", face = "bold"))

km_plot
```

[image: ggsurvplot with expanded axes not lining up with table]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the same `x` scale on `km_plot$table` as you did with `km_plot$plot`

```r
km_plot$table <- km_plot$table + layer_scales(km_plot$plot)$x
km_plot
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to remove the Y axis line of the table?

Comment: @krtbris yes, the `km_plot$table` object is just a ggplot, so you can add a `theme` to it, such as `km_plot$table <- km_plot$table + theme(axis.line.x = element_blank())`